# Line spacing on wrapped text

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I am currently building content in SharePoint, media & Content WebPart, using Calibri, font size 12pt. I notice that when text wraps it creates a spacing. I would like to have 0pt spacing between wrapped text, how would I accomplish this?

Best,
Lost & Confused

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to style the `line-height` property of your html. Something like this:

```
<style>
.ms-rtestate-field{
    line-height:1.2;
}
</style>
```

That will change the line-height for all content-editors on your page. You might also want to apply that to some other selector as well, perhaps `#s4-bodyContainer`.

In general small line height is more difficult to read. And of course it depends upon the font as well.

Calibri has a fairly tall [x-height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height) -- the height of lower case letters, like x, compared to capital letters or letters with risers/descenders. The conventional wisdom is that fonts with tall x-height need a little bit more line spacing to help with legibility. So I would recommend not making it too small. (unless, of course, you don't want people to read it!)

**Edit**

Just realized that you might not know how to add css to a page....

Add a script editor webpart to your page. Edit the snippet and place the code from above. That will just change it for that one page.

If you want to change it for your whole site, you might create a css file using a text editor or something like dreamweaver. You can then put that file in your **style library** or **site-assets** folder. You can then add that style to your masterpage or page layouts.